# Warning: X may be used uninitialized in this function

Tags: c, warnings

I am writing a custom "vector" struct. I do not understand why I'm getting a `Warning: "one" may be used uninitialized` here.

This is my vector.h file

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

typedef struct Vector{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}Vector;

#endif /* VECTOR_ */
```

The warning happens here on line `one->a = 12`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include "vector.h"

int main(void){
    Vector* one;
    one->a = 12;
    one->b = 13;
    one->c = -11;
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`one` has not been assigned so points to an unpredictable location.  You should either place it on the stack:

```
Vector one;
one.a = 12;
one.b = 13;
one.c = -11
```

or dynamically allocate memory for it:

```
Vector* one = malloc(sizeof(*one))
one->a = 12;
one->b = 13;
one->c = -11
free(one);
```

Note the use of `free` in this case.  In general, you'll need exactly one call to `free` for each call made to `malloc`.

Answer (score 21):

You get the warning because you did not assign a value to `one`, which is a pointer. This is undefined behavior.

You should declare it like this:

```
Vector* one = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
```

or like this:

```
Vector one;
```

in which case you need to replace `->` operator with `.` like this:

```
one.a = 12;
one.b = 13;
one.c = -11;
```

Finally, in C99 and later you can use *designated initializers*:

```
Vector one = {
   .a = 12
,  .b = 13
,  .c = -11
};
```

Answer (score 9):

When you use `Vector *one` you are merely creating a pointer to the structure but there is no memory allocated to it.

Simply use `one = (Vector *)malloc(sizeof(Vector));` to declare memory and instantiate it.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most professional solution, but instead of initialising it using `malloc`, you can also initialise it using `new`:

`Vector *one = new Vector();`

I personally find it more elegant.

Comment: This applies to C++ only, not to C.