# Why I'am getting this error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\0.3.r5958\luascript.cpp|9037|error: 'buttonEnter' may be used uninitialized in this function|
C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\0.3.r5958\luascript.cpp|9037|error: 'buttonEscape' may be used uninitialized in this function|
C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\0.3.r5958\luascript.cpp|9039|error: 'popup' may be used uninitialized in this function|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|strong text
```

This are the lines were I get the error:

```
    std::string str, title, message;
    uint8_t buttonEnter, buttonEscape;
    std::vector<ModalChoice> buttons, choices;
    bool popup;
```

I'm using c++ and trying to compile in Code Blocks

Comment: Probably the same reason this dude was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958931/c-warning-x-may-be-used-uninitialized-in-this-function Ive downvoted as you dont even mention the language you are using.

Comment: Just read the compiler error. It is telling you exactly what is going on.

Comment: Sorry but I'm just learning the language

Comment: yes - you have not initialized them.

Comment: I'm going to say ... because you haven't initialized them.

Comment: OK, when declared in this context, primitive types (such as `int`, `double`, `bool`, etc) are not initialized. That means their value could be anything. Your compiler settings must be quite strict, because usually this would only yield a warning. So just initialize them: `uint8_t buttonEnter = 0` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared your objects and variables, but you haven't initialized them. `bool popup` simply *declares* that you will be using a boolean with the name `popup`, however it doesn't *initialize* it. Initializing means setting an initial value, in this case it would be `true` or `false`.

Often times declaring and initializing are done together, eg `bool popup = true;`. If you don't initialize your values, the behavior is undefined. Sometimes there are default values implemented by certain compilers, but this is **not** to be relied upon. You should assume you will get garbage values if you don't.

Comment: thanks, sorry for this post but I'm learning the language

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are on.But i think its because you give declare them,but do not define them i.e give them default values.